# Windows 10 RDP - which process to restart, when getting Windows Update as blue window with gear?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-update

I use Windows 10 over Remote Desktop Protocol (typically with `remmina` on a Linux Client).

Very often, the usage is fine; then I disconnect the remmina client from the Windows 10 RDP server; then I log in after some time again - and then the Windows 10 desktop icons, or taskbar, or both are frozen - but I can do Ctrl-Alt-Esc to start Task Manager, and from there run (via File / Run new task): `ms-settings:windowsupdate` - and then Windows Update does want to start, but all I get is a blue window with a gear:

[image: windows update blue window]

Sometimes this hangs on for a couple of minutes, then the window becomes normal; but sometimes it hangs on for hours.

Here's the kicker: restarting Explorer (e.g. with `taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer` in Administrator Command Prompts) does **NOT** help with this (well occasionally it might, but mostly, Explorer restarts, and the Windows Update / Settings window is still blue with a gear).

So, if not restarting Explorer - what process should I restart to get back normal behavior of desktop, without restarting the computer, or logging off/logging on the Windows user again (both of which would destroy the session, and lose any unsaved stuff)?

Comment: restarting really is the best option here. You can do that from a commandline by typing `shutdown -r -t 0`